# Negative Y value for background-position will not change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/6TbTDVs.jpg);
    background-position: center top;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();

    var move = (scrolledY*0.2);

    $('div').css('background-position','center -'+move*-1+'px');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rgbjoy/8GkSg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're concatenating a `-` in front of the number *and* multiply it by `-1`, so it's trying to set the position to something like `center --6px`, which is not valid.

Try this:

```
var move = scrolledY * -0.2;
$('div').css('background-position','center '+move+'px');
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/8GkSg/1/)

Comment: ...I think I need another cup of coffee. Thank you so much.